# limit of the triple integral

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I found $\iiint_E$ $1\over (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{n/2}$ *dV*, where *E* is the region bounded by the spheres with radiuses *r* and *R* (both positive), is $4\pi\left(\frac{R^{3-n}}{3-n}-\frac{r^{3-n}}{3-n}\right)$.

For what values of n does the integral have a limit as  $r\to0^+$?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, while $n>3$ and $r\to 0^+$ then $$\frac{r^{3-n}}{3-n}\to\infty$$ And clearly we should keep $n$ not to touch $3$.

Comment: Well done ! + 1